# Why doesn't this Discriminated Union accept a Set type case?

Tags: types, f#, set, discriminated-union

I am trying to create a new `Set` type:

```
type MySet<'t> = | List of list<'t>
                 | Sequence of seq<'t>
                 | Array of 't []
```

This works, but if I try to add a case for the `Set` type itself I get a message: `a type parameter is missing a constraint 'when t: comparison'`

```
type MySet<'t> = | List of list<'t>
                 | Sequence of seq<'t>
                 | Array of 't []
                 | Set of Set<'T>
```

My guess is this should be easy to fix, but I could not do it even though I tried a couple of things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The implementation of the `Set<'t>` data structure requires that its values can be compared, so if your type contains values that can be put into a set, you must provide the same type constraint:

```
type MySet<'t when 't : comparison> =
    | List of list<'t>
    | Sequence of seq<'t>
    | Array of 't []
    | Set of Set<'t>
```